# Python Pandas ValueError from Regression Model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have a data frame "df" with columns "id", "date", "price", "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "sqft_living", and "sqft_lot". The "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "sqft_living", and "sqft_lot" columns contain missing data entries.

[image]

I created a regression model by filling the missing column values based on the values of the other columns. The missing value would be determined by observing the other columns and making a prediction based on the other column values. The following command is used to fill in the missing values in the "bedrooms" column. I have commands to do the same for the missing "bathrooms", "sqft_living", and "sqft_lot" columns.

```
# Replace missing bedrooms count
clean_bed = df[df['bedrooms'] != '']
x1 = clean_bed.iloc[:, [4,5,6]].values
y1 = clean_bed['bedrooms'].values

lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x1, y1)

# Get the rows to do prediction on
predict_bedrooms = df[df['bedrooms'] == ''].iloc[:, [4,5,6]].values

# Perform prediction
lm.predict(predict_bedrooms)

missing_bedrooms = df[df['bedrooms'] == ''].index
df.loc[missing_bedrooms, 'bedrooms'] = lm.predict(predict_bedrooms)
```

I got the following error message when running the above command.

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

Is there a way to fix this error message? I was advised that I need to check that my outputs fit the dtype('float64') criteria, but I'm unsure of how to do so.

Comment: did you check if your dataframe values are nan or infinite?

Comment: that's because `LinearRegression` doesn't support NaN (or None) values. Get rid of rows with NaNs or fill them with values (e.g. `fillna` or `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer`).

Comment: @Rafaó I'm using the code marked `# Replace missing bedrooms count` to fill in the missing values. However, I'm having a problem filling in the missing values because I get the ValueError message.

Comment: you filter out only empty strings, try `df.dropna(inplace=True)` or `df=df.dropna()`

Comment: @Rafaó Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the code I wrote for replacing the missing bedrooms count?

Comment: That's why you need to pre-process the dataset.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh How do you do that?

Comment: Do what? Preprocess? It depends on what you want to do, but in this case you can’t use LinearRegression, because you have NaNs in the data. If you want to get rid of them, use dropna instead of filtering out empty strings.